# Customize header logo link via the admin

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, header, logo

I am working with a custom theme in Magento 2.1.  I would like site administrators to be able to set the header logo's link via the admin config.  This link would then be used in **app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml**.

By default, I believe it uses `$this->getUrl('')` to point to the store's home page.  However, I need this to point to an external URL, and the URL depends on which environment the site is running on (i.e. dev, staging, prod).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to create a redirect link, and link to that from the logo.  This way, site administrators can update the link as needed.

In app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml, I changed the link to:

```
<a class="logo" href="<?php print $this->getUrl('sitehome');?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $storeName ?>">
```

Then, in the admin at Marketing > URL Rewrites, I created a rewrite URL for "sitehome."  That link goes to an external URL.

Hope this helps somebody. :)